# redirect page after user login (php code)

Tags: php, redirect

I have problem in redirect from login page after process check username and password and not redirect to main page. please anyone can check my code and give me hint or guide(website) to repair this error.

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
?>
<?php
    include("config.php");
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // username and password sent from form 
        $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['uname']);
        $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['psw']); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE UserName = '$myusername' and Password = '$mypassword'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
            header("Location: welcome.php");
        }else {
            $error = "<center>
                        <img src='images/logo.jpg'>
                        <p>
                            <font size='4'>Your Login Name or Password is 
invalid</font>
                            <p>
                                <font size='5'><a href='index.php'>Back to MainPage
                                </a>
                                </font>
                    <center>";
            echo "";
        }
    }
?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <style type = "text/css">
       body {
       font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       font-size:14px;
       }
       label {
       font-weight:bold;
       width:100px;
       font-size:14px;
       }
       .box {
        border:#666666 solid 1px;
       }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">
        <div align = "center">
            <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
                <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
                <div style = "margin:30px">
                    <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>   
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Check the "Help" to see how to format code [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Don't store clear passwords in database. Use [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/password_verify).

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Where is the form that launches this script

Comment: You could use some work on the Error section. You seem to have some badly formed HTML in there that is likely to cause other odd occurances. Also the `<font>` tag has been deprecated now for a long time

Comment: Please look at examples for `Location` in the [manual page for `header()`](https://php.net/header). I admit the manual doesn't state it explicitly, but the all function does is to send an HTTP header—it won't stop script.

Comment: ^^^^ So it should be followed by an `exit` ^^^^^

Comment: What do you actually see on the page when this script completes

Answer (score 1):

Be carrefull to not write any caracter to the output before **header** function.
Your code start with

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
?>
<?php
    include("config.php");
    ...
?>
```

Avoid using **?>{CR/LF}<?php** in you code but use :

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
    include('config.php');
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    ...
?>
```

Check if **session.php** and **config.php** writes some output caracters too...

If one caracter is sent to output before using **header** function, the redirection will never be done.

Add an **exit** or **die** function just after the **header** one to be sure to stop code execution.

Check previous answers for SQL injection too :-)

Good Luck.